# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#

> System.TypeInitializationException: "The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectAttrs' threw an exception."

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Here is the code and the row 67 where the error is detected. If i delete row 67, everything works without error, but because in the row 70 the table is used for veryfing the data check, it will always give the second answer because without adapter.Fill(table) there will be no changes and always will be 0 rows.

Here is the code:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yci9D.png)

[Full Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTr3A.png)

the code:

```
namespace Assestment
{
    public partial class SignInForm : Form
    {


 //Sign In button and data check'
        private void Sibutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String signinUser = lfield.Text;
            String passUser = pfield.Text;

            DB db = new DB();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Login`= @uS AND `Password`= @uP ", db.GetConnection());
            command.Parameters.Add("@uS", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = signinUser;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            

            if (table.Rows.Count > 0)

                MessageBox.Show("Succesful");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password or Username");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't post a link to your code but post the code here. A link may become stale after some time and then your question cannot be used for future reference by others. You can also post your images here but code would be better. So add the code and also the image with the error.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/